# Deploy containers from inside another container using Rancher-Cli

Tags: docker, containers, rancher

I need to deploy a dockerize service from inside another docker container. I'm using Rancher to cattle my services, and rancher-cli to deploy them, the rancher-cli version I'm using is 0.6.13 (in my local machine and inside the container).

I'm able to create a new stack from inside the container but the service I've set in my docker-compose.yml are not created.

This is the script I'm using to deploy the services:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Creating dummy device..."

rancher --debug  up \
    --rancher-file /opt/deploy/rancher-compose.yml \
    --file /opt/deploy/docker-compose.yml \
    --stack dummy-stack
```

This is my docker compose, (I'm tryign to deploy the simplest docker image):

```
version: '2'
services:
  dummy-device:
    image: hello-world 
    tty: true
```

And the rancher-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
catalog:
  name: Dummy Device
  version: 0.0.1
  minimum_rancher_version: 1.6.28
  description: Dummy Device
```

Using this config I can deploy the new stack and service from my local machine, but from inside the a container (based on Ubuntu 18.04 image) the LOGS get stuck here:

```
DEBU[0000] Opening compose files: /opt/deploy/docker-compose.yml,/opt/deploy/rancher-compose.yml
DEBU[0000] Looking for stack dummy-stack
INFO[0000] Creating stack dummy-stack
DEBU[0000] Project [dummy-stack]: Creating project
DEBU[0000] Project [dummy-stack]: Project created
DEBU[0000] Project [dummy-stack]: Starting project
DEBU[0000] Project [dummy-stack]: Project started
```